# Why this implementation of Bellman-Ford doesn't work?

Tags: graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

The following example contains a negative cycle, and yet the program doesn't seem to find it. Can someone point out what is wrong? It is supposed to print out a negative cycle if one exists, but the program doesn't do what is expected.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

// a structure to represent a weighted edge in graph
struct Edge
{
    int src, dest, weight;
};

// a structure to represent a connected, directed and weighted graph
struct Graph
{
    // V-> Number of vertices, E-> Number of edges
    int V, E;

    // graph is represented as an array of edges.
    struct Edge* edge;
};

// Creates a graph with V vertices and E edges
struct Graph* createGraph(int V, int E)
{
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc( sizeof(struct Graph) );
    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;

    graph->edge = (struct Edge*) malloc( graph->E * sizeof( struct Edge ) );

    return graph;
}

// A utility function used to print the solution
void printArr(int dist[], int n)
{
    printf("Vertex   Distance from Source\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d \t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]);
}

// The main function that finds shortest distances from src to all other
// vertices using Bellman-Ford algorithm.  The function also detects negative
// weight cycle
void BellmanFord(struct Graph* graph, int src)
{
    int V = graph->V;
    int E = graph->E;
    int dist[V];

    // Step 1: Initialize distances from src to all other vertices as INFINITE
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        dist[i]   = INT_MAX;
    dist[src] = 0;

    // Step 2: Relax all edges |V| - 1 times. A simple shortest path from src
    // to any other vertex can have at-most |V| - 1 edges
    for (int i = 1; i <= V-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < E; j++)
        {
            int u = graph->edge[j].src;
            int v = graph->edge[j].dest;
            int weight = graph->edge[j].weight;
            if (dist[u] + weight < dist[v])
                dist[v] = dist[u] + weight;
        }
    }

    // Step 3: check for negative-weight cycles.  The above step guarantees
    // shortest distances if graph doesn't contain negative weight cycle.
    // If we get a shorter path, then there is a cycle.
    for (int i = 0; i < E; i++)
    {
        int u = graph->edge[i].src;
        int v = graph->edge[i].dest;
        int weight = graph->edge[i].weight;
        if (dist[u] + weight < dist[v])
            printf("Graph contains negative weight cycle");
    }

    printArr(dist, V);

    return;
}

void CurrencyArbExample()
{
 /* Let us create the graph given in above example */
int V = 3;  // Number of vertices in graph
int E = 6;  // Number of edges in graph
struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V, E);

enum Nodes
{
  USD,
  EUR,
  GBP
};

double USDEUR = .8;
double EURGBP = .8;
double GBPUSD = 1.7;

double logUSDEUR = log(USDEUR);
double logEURGBP = log(EURGBP);
double logGBPUSD = log(GBPUSD);

double logOneOverUSDEUR = log(1.0 / USDEUR);
double logOneOverEURGBP = log(1.0 / EURGBP);
double logOneOverGBPUSD = log(1.0 / GBPUSD);

std::cout << logUSDEUR << " " << logEURGBP << " " << logGBPUSD << " "
          << logOneOverUSDEUR << " " << logOneOverEURGBP << " " << logOneOverGBPUSD
          << std::endl;

//("usd", "euro") : log(1/usd_euro),
//("euro", "gbp") : log(1/euro_gbp),
//("gbp", "usd") : log(1/gbp_usd),
//("euro", "usd") : log(usd_euro),
//("gbp", "euro") : log(euro_gbp),
//("usd", "gbp") : log(gbp_usd)

graph->edge[0].src = USD;
graph->edge[0].dest = EUR;
graph->edge[0].weight = logOneOverUSDEUR;

graph->edge[1].src = EUR;
graph->edge[1].dest = GBP;
graph->edge[1].weight = logOneOverEURGBP;

graph->edge[2].src = GBP;
graph->edge[2].dest = USD;
graph->edge[2].weight = logOneOverGBPUSD;

graph->edge[3].src = EUR;
graph->edge[3].dest = USD;
graph->edge[3].weight = logUSDEUR;

graph->edge[4].src = GBP;
graph->edge[4].dest = EUR;
graph->edge[4].weight = logEURGBP;

graph->edge[5].src = USD;
graph->edge[5].dest = GBP;
graph->edge[5].weight = logGBPUSD;


BellmanFord(graph, 0);
}


// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    CurrencyArbExample();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I modified the function CurrencyArbExample since I believe the graph was being set up incorrectly before. I think this is correct, but I still don't seem to get the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `weight` attribute of struct `Edge` is of type `int` while you assign `double` values, namely the computed logarithms of exchanges rates.

turn on the warnings of your compiler, you should receive type narrowing warnings (at least).

Comment: I God, I feel like an utter moron. Thanks.